# How Can Get Selected item id value in Dynamic Spinner in android

Tags: android, android-spinner

I create dynamic spinner in android which show `json` data from url I set data properly in spinner but i get id of selected item

How can i do this

My code for set spinner value is :

private void setSpinData() {

```
    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.setTimeout(800000);
        final RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

        client.get("Here is url", new TextHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode,
                                  cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] 
            headers, String responseString,
                                  Throwable throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(SpinnerActivity.this, responseString,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode,
                                  cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] 
            headers, String responseString) {
                if (responseString != null) {

                    try {

                        JSONObject response = new 
           JSONObject(responseString);
                        Log.e("responseString",""+responseString);


                        String status = response.getString("status");

                        if (status.equals("success")) {

                             JSONArray jsonArray = 
                             response.getJSONArray("car_rate");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                              JSONObject 
                              jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                              String type = jsonObject1.getString("type");
                              btclist1.add(type);
                              cartype_id= jsonObject1.getString("cartype_id");



                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    spin_value.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(SpinnerActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, btclist1));

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SpinnerActivity.this, "data is not available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }else {
        Toast.makeText(SpinnerActivity.this, "No Internet connection",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And my `json` response is:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "car_rate": [
        {
            "cartype_id": "5",
            "type": "SUV PerMiles",
            "rate_type": "1",
            "rate_in": "12"
        },
        {
            "cartype_id": "6",
            "type": "SUV Hourly",
            "rate_type": "0",
            "rate_in": "50"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can i get `cartype_id` of selected spinner item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a **`MyModel`** like this

```
public class MyModel
{
    String cartype_id,type,rate_type,rate_in;

    public String getCartype_id() {
        return cartype_id;
    }

    public void setCartype_id(String cartype_id) {
        this.cartype_id = cartype_id;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getRate_type() {
        return rate_type;
    }

    public void setRate_type(String rate_type) {
        this.rate_type = rate_type;
    }

    public String getRate_in() {
        return rate_in;
    }

    public void setRate_in(String rate_in) {
        this.rate_in = rate_in;
    }
}
```

> Than create a **`ArrayList`** of your Model Class

```
ArrayList<MyModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

> Parse your json like this

```
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray =
                response.getJSONArray("car_rate");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {


            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            MyModel myModel= new MyModel();
            myModel.setCartype_id(obj.getString("cartype_id"));
            myModel.setType(obj.getString("type"));
            myModel.setRate_in(obj.getString("rate_type"));
            myModel.setRate_in(obj.getString("rate_in"));


            arrayList.add(myModel);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

> Now create a custom adapter like this

```
class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyModel> {

    private ArrayList<MyModel> myarrayList;

    SpinnerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<MyModel> modelArrayList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, modelArrayList);
        this.myarrayList = modelArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, parent);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public MyModel getItem(int position) {
        return myarrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int count = myarrayList.size();
        //return count > 0 ? count - 1 : count;
        return count;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, parent);
    }

    private View getCustomView(int position, ViewGroup parent) {
        MyModel model = getItem(position);

        View spinnerRow = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, parent, false);

        TextView label = spinnerRow.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        label.setText(String.format("%s", model != null ? model.getType() : ""));

        return spinnerRow;
    }
}
```

> Now set adapter in your spinner like this

```
SpinnerAdapter adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, arrayList);
        mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

> Now get selected item form your spinner like this

```
    mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            MyModel myModel=(MyModel) parent.getSelectedItem();
            Log.e("DATA",myModel.getCartype_id());
            Log.e("DATA",myModel.getRate_in());
            Log.e("DATA",myModel.getRate_type());
            Log.e("DATA",myModel.getType());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    

        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray =
                    response.getJSONArray("car_rate");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {


                JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                MyModel myModel= new MyModel();
                myModel.setCartype_id(obj.getString("cartype_id"));
                myModel.setType(obj.getString("type"));
                myModel.setRate_in(obj.getString("rate_type"));
                myModel.setRate_in(obj.getString("rate_in"));


                arrayList.add(myModel);

            }

            SpinnerAdapter adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, arrayList);
            mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                MyModel myModel=(MyModel) parent.getSelectedItem();
                Log.e("DATA",myModel.getCartype_id());
                Log.e("DATA",myModel.getRate_in());
                Log.e("DATA",myModel.getRate_type());
                Log.e("DATA",myModel.getType());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });


    }
```